# Why do I get an AttributeError when performing a unit test, on Jupiter Notebook?

Tags: python, unit-testing, jupyter-notebook

To solve an exercise on Jupiter Notebook, I need to perform a unit test on a function that I called *city_function*

```
def city_function(city, country):

   output = city.title() + ', ' + country.title()

   return output
```

This function is stored in "city_functions.py". The code that performs the unit test is stored in "test_cities2.ipynb". And I tried the following code to do the unit test:

```
import unittest 



from city_functions import city_function


class CityCountryTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    # Verify if city_function works



    def test_city_country_function(self):

        output = city_function('lisbon', 'portugal')

        self.assertEqual(output, 'Lisbon, Portugal')



unittest.main()
```

And I got an AttributeError of the type: AttributeError: module '**main**' has no attribute.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good [article](https://medium.com/@vladbezden/using-python-unittest-in-ipython-or-jupyter-732448724e31), that describes your problem:

> The reason is that unittest.main looks at `sys.argv` and first parameter is what started IPython or Jupyter, therefore the error about kernel connection file not being a valid attribute. Passing explicit list to `unittest.main` will prevent IPython and Jupyter look at `sys.argv`. Passing `exit=False` will prevent `unittest.main` to shutdown the kernell process

Your last line should be like this:

`unittest.main(argv=['first-arg-is-ignored'], exit=False)`